# How to use Netty ChannelHandler with gzip?

Tags: gzip, netty

I want to compress and uncompress with `Gzip` using Netty ChannelHandler, I was trying for a while, but always got a bit difficulty. My code is below:

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
pipeline.addLast("inflater", new HttpContentDecompressor());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor());
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think your channel handlers are in the wrong order, this is how I have mine:

```
    pipeline.addLast(DECODE, decoderProvider.get());
    pipeline.addLast(ENCODE, encoderProvider.get());
    pipeline.addLast(COMPRESS, compressorProvider.get());
    pipeline.addLast(DECOMPRESS, decompressorProvider.get());
    pipeline.addLast(AGGREGATE, aggregatorProvider.get());
    pipeline.addLast(EXECUTE, new CustomRequestHandler();
```

Comment: Your answer is a reordering of the question, and I'm not saying the question deserves anything more, but do you happen to have a reasonable code snippet? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48046007/839733

Comment: The order is the only important factor in this case.